# "Rails Style" - nested routes in in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

as far as I understood the concept of nested routes in ember, they only seem to be representing nested views.
But what if I dont want to nest views, but want to have nested Routes like in Rails, e.g.

`user_entities_path(@user)`

which should show a list of all Entities (a random model) for the given user.

How do I accomplish this in Ember (or more precisly: In ember using Rails as a backend)?
What should my `router.js` look like and do I need a `users_entities_route.js`?